# Unable to resolve hostname using `kubectl logs` or `kubectl exec`

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

I've created a Kubernetes cluster using CoreOS on AWS and I'm having trouble communicating with nodes from the master.

For example, operations like `kubectl exec` or `kubectl logs` fail an error similar to the following:

```
Error from server: dial tcp: lookup ip-XXX-X-XXX-XXX.eu-west-1.compute.internal: no such host
```

I've found some issues on Github that describe the problem so I know the team knows about this bug, but I would like to ask here if its possible to use some workaround until it gets addressed somehow.

One workaround mentioned was to use the `--hostname-override` flag but as I'm on AWS, this flag is ignored (see [#22984](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22984))

Related issues on GitHub: [#22770](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22770) [#22063](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22063).

Comment: I'm using kubelet:v1.3.0-alpha.3 also meet this problem, --hostname-override works for me

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure you're using the right context?

```
kubectl config use-context my-cluster-name
```